# how to attached text file and pdf file or any type of file in iOS /android?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am working on Ionic with cordova .I want to select any type of file from file explore or gallery (may be .txt,pdf,.jpg any type )  Then I need to send to  server that the attached file .So i google it and found there is some plugin

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/imagePicker/

which is used in only picking the images .But I need for all files like txt and pdf and image also
and for transferring file 
I found this plugin 
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/

**Second option**

```
<input  type=“file”/>
```

But it not work for android I saw on google and it crashes at IOS at OS 8.1

could you please suggest how to attached files in iOS .?

Comment: Have you tried [`cordova-filepicker`](https://github.com/albertut/cordova-filepicker)?

Answer (score 1):

Normal `input` with type file will not work for choosing file from native devices using `cordova`. You have to use plugin for this, please try `cordova` [file picker plugin.](https://github.com/albertut/cordova-filepicker)